# read only lines which start with alphabets a-z vb.net

Tags: vb.net-2010

i want to read from a text file only those lines which  start with alphabets a-z vb.net

currently I am using ReadToEnd.

fileReader = New StreamReader(OpenFile.FileName)

```
        Dim fileread1 As String = fileReader.ReadToEnd

        'For i = 0 To linesarray1.GetUpperBound(0)
        '    If linesarray1(i).StartsWith("a-z") Then
        '        r_text_file2.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & linesarray1(i))
        '    End If
        'Next
```

but not working

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "not working" means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this.

```
For i = 0 To linesarray1.GetUpperBound(0)
    If  Char.IsLetter(linesarray1(i).substring(0,1)) Then
        r_text_file2.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & linesarray1(i))
    End If
Next
```

With this you can check if the first position is a Letter.

If you use this you should first check that your sting length is > 0 to prevent exceptions.

**Edit:**

If you like to check that the string don't starts with "p" change the if to:

```
If  Char.IsLetter(linesarray1(i).substring(0,1)) And not linesarray1(i).substring(0,1) = "p" Then 
...
```

Comment: you are truly awesome Nik Bo. it worked for me as i want. i used it as  


           For i = 0 To linesarray1.GetUpperBound(0)
                If linesarray1(i).Length > 1 Then
                    If Char.IsLetter(linesarray1(i).Substring(0, 1)) Then
                        r_text_file2.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & linesarray1(i))
                    End If
                End If
            Next

Comment: Nice to hear that this helped.

Comment: can you confirm if i want to ignore string which start only with letter "p"

Comment: Do you want to check if the string starts with "a-z" and not "p" right?

Comment: yes Nik bo, i want to check if the string starts with "a-z" and not "p" right

Comment: You Really rocks Nik Bo. :) :) :)            Thank you so so so much :):):) you solved my problem :):):)

Comment: You are welcome. With the check mark you can mark this answer as solution, to Close your question.

Comment: i am new to this forum so how can i mark it as solved ?

Comment: On the left side of every Question and Answer you see a up and down arrow. Between this is a number which represents how the Post got voted by community (+1 for upvote -1 Point for down vote) At Answers you see as post owner a check mark (Grey) if you click on it you mark an answer as the right. In other Posts you see a green check mark if the owner markt an answer as right.

Answer (score 0):

The sample you posted will read lines only if they start with the exact string "**a-z**"

What I think you should be looking for is `System.Char.IsLetter(linesarray1(i)(0))`

but do also check for null and empty strings before invoking the above method.

edit:

see the msdn documentation for `IsLetter` here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isletter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Additionally, if case is important, the `Char` class has `IsUpper` and `IsLower` methods also.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. See above, where I suggest the IsLetter method. You can similarly check for lower case if you need to. See the help link  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isletter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx